# Is it possible to use MapObjects Java with ArcIMS 10?

Tags: java, arcims

Is it possible to use MapObjects Java with ArcIMS 10? We are starting to look at migrating our MOJava solution to run against ArcIMS 10, has anyone been successful in migrating to ArcIMS 10?

Our initial testing is indicating that there are problems with some of our feature layers. The layers don't return any geometries to the MOJava client. But the layers workes in ArcMap.

We are currrently runnig on ArcIMS 9.2 so any migrations issues for ArcIMS 9.3 might be intressting as well. According to the [what's new in ArcIMS 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcims/10.0/mainhelp/arcims_help.htm) there are no changes to ArcXML.

Update: Using MessageConsole in JoViewPlus gives this error message against the ArcIMS 10 layers:

```
> 2010-okt-31 11:12:08:    com.esri.mo2.client.aims.d
com.esri.mo2.client.aims.InvalidStreamDataException: A general exception has occurred: (Invalid data has been detected within the FeatureStream: <' "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ARCXML version="1.1">
<RESPONSE>
<ERROR machine="hsovimsu5" processid="2848" threadid="2940">AXLParser: POLYGON tag incorrect.</ERROR>
</RESPONSE>
</ARCXML")
> 2010-okt-31 11:12:08:    com.esri.mo2.client.aims.d
com.esri.mo2.client.aims.InvalidStreamDataException: A general exception has occurred: (Invalid data has been detected within the FeatureStream: <' "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ARCXML version="1.1">
<RESPONSE>
<ERROR machine="hsovimsu5" processid="2848" threadid="2968">AXLParser: POLYGON tag incorrect.</ERROR>
</RESPONSE>
</ARCXML")
> 2010-okt-31 11:12:08:    com.esri.mo2.client.aims.d
com.esri.mo2.client.aims.InvalidStreamDataException: A general exception has occurred: (Invalid data has been detected within the FeatureStream: <' "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ARCXML version="1.1">
<RESPONSE>
<ERROR machine="hsovimsu5" processid="2848" threadid="2940">AXLParser: POLYGON tag incorrect.</ERROR>
</RESPONSE>
</ARCXML")
> 2010-okt-31 11:12:08:    com.esri.mo2.client.aims.d
com.esri.mo2.client.aims.InvalidStreamDataException: A general exception has occurred: (Invalid data has been detected within the FeatureStream: <' "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ARCXML version="1.1">
<RESPONSE>
<ERROR machine="hsovimsu5" processid="2848" threadid="2968">AXLParser: POLYGON tag incorrect.</ERROR>
</RESPONSE>
</ARCXML")
```

More info: Talked to a colleague about this and we only have problems on some of our feature layers, all our images layers are ok. It seems to be connected to the scale of the map because sometimes it shows up when zooming in to different scale intervals. We have removed all scale dependent rendering, so it's not an renderer issue causing this. More likely that it might be some kind of generalization involved. Also the layer we are having problems with is a layer with multi part polygons. Has anyone been able to successfully migrate to ArcIMS 10?

Answer (score 1):

ArcIMS is to be deprecated in the next release (10.1) - arriving Q4 2010

http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/ArcGIS10and101Deprecation_Plan.pdf
page 2

http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=38202

Recommend you work your thoughts onto ArcGIS Server 10.1 (64-bit)
(on page 3 of the pdf) for future proofing your project.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that and we are migrating from MOJava and ArcIMS into ArcGIS Engine and ArcGIS Server but it will take while. So the reson to migrate to ArcIMS 10 is maintainability so we get less servers to maintain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 10.1 doesn't arrive Q4 2010, it's more likely to be Q2 2011. SP1 (10.01) on the other hand will hit Q4 2010.

Answer (score 1):

As you are already aware that ArcIMS is on the way out, your probably also aware that MO is also pretty much phased out. But for anyone else stumbling on this post, h[ere is the link to MO product life cycle.](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/product%20life%20cycle/mo_/MOWindows_PLC.pdf)

I know that little has changed with ArcIMS between 9.3.1 and 10 (and to some extent, also 9.3).  It has mainly been bug fixes.  So if it was [do-able at an older version](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc01/professional/papers/pap456/p456.htm), it would be likely that it would still be possible at 10.  However, I have no experience with MO, so cannot comment further.

Comment: Well note that the question is on MapObjects Java Edition not windows. http://downloads2.esri.com/support/product%20life%20cycle/moje_/MOJava_PLC.pdf even if the same is true for MOJava as well. We had big problems with "bug fixes" when migrating to ArcIMS 9.2 so I'm not as sure that it will work.